# Can't make item through Exact Online REST API

Tags: php, rest, exact-online

I have been struggling to get the Exact Online Api to work. It should be possible to make items through the API, but the API isn't allowing me to make 1.

As result of an earlier problem, I got recommended to switch to the unofficial picquer library: [Found here](https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client).

I got the following code:

```
$itemModel->CostPriceNew = $newPrice;
$itemModel->CostPriceStandard = $standardPrice;
$itemModel->Description = $description;
$itemModel->Code = $code;
$itemModel->SearchCode = $searchCode;
$itemModel->IsSalesItem = false;
$itemModel->IsPurchaseItem = true;
$itemModel->Unit = 'pc';
$itemModel->IsTime = false;
$itemModel->CostPriceCurrency = 'EUR';
$itemModel->IsStockItem = false;
$itemModel->IsSubcontractedItem = false;
$itemModel->IsPackageItem = false;
$itemModel->IsSerialItem = false;
$itemModel->IsSerialNumberItem = false;
$itemModel->IsFractionAllowedItem = false;
$itemModel->StartDate = $startDate;
$itemModel->EndDate = $endDate;
$itemModel->ItemGroup = $itemGroup;
$itemModel->save();
```

I found it frustating that so much is required when the documentation ([Exact Api Item information](https://start.exactonline.nl/docs/HlpRestAPIResourcesDetails.aspx?name=LogisticsItems)) says only 2 are required.

Anyway, the code goes wrong on :

```
$itemModel->Unit = 'pc';
```

> Error 500: A problem has occurred. The cause of this issue will be investigated as soon as possible.

I double checked if the code existed, changed into a different one. Made a custom code to test with.
If I remove the line, it gives me the error

> Error 500: Required: Unit

If I alter the code to a non-existing code:

> Error 500: Invalid reference: Units

To test, I made a product on the Exact website. I retrieved it through the API and gave the Unit to my new product. The same error popped up.

I made a ticket, but Exact cant find anything wrong on their side.

Anyone encountered this before and has a solution for it?

edit: my json:

```
{
    "ExtraDescription": "Child from 75 . Number 24 out of 25",
    "CostPriceNew": 170,
    "CostPriceStandard": 170,
    "Description": "Vrouwentongen",
    "Code": "3255",
    "SearchCode": "3255",
    "IsSalesItem": false,
    "IsPurchaseItem": true,
    "Unit": "pc",
    "IsTime": false,
    "CostPriceCurrency": "EUR",
    "IsStockItem": false,
    "IsSubcontractedItem": false,
    "IsPackageItem": false,
    "IsSerialItem": false,
    "IsSerialNumberItem": false,
    "IsFractionAllowedItem": false,
    "StartDate": "2005-01-01T12:00",
    "EndDate": "2030-12-12T12:00",
    "ItemGroup": "4078e7a5-a61c-4751-8875-875f36810554",
    "IsBatchNumberItem": 0,
    "Class_01": null,
    "Class_02": null,
    "Class_03": null,
    "Class_04": null,
    "Class_05": null,
    "CopyRemarks": 0,
    "Created": null,
    "CreatorFullName": null,
    "Creator": null,
    "Division": null,
    "FreeBoolField_01": null,
    "FreeBoolField_02": null,
    "FreeBoolField_03": null,
    "FreeBoolField_04": null,
    "FreeBoolField_05": null,
    "FreeDateField_01": null,
    "FreeDateField_02": null,
    "FreeDateField_03": null,
    "FreeDateField_04": null,
    "FreeDateField_05": null,
    "FreeNumberField_01": null,
    "FreeNumberField_02": null,
    "FreeNumberField_03": null,
    "FreeNumberField_04": null,
    "FreeNumberField_05": null,
    "FreeNumberField_06": null,
    "FreeNumberField_07": null,
    "FreeNumberField_08": null,
    "FreeTextField_01": null,
    "FreeTextField_02": null,
    "FreeTextField_03": null,
    "FreeTextField_04": null,
    "FreeTextField_05": null,
    "FreeTextField_06": null,
    "FreeTextField_07": null,
    "FreeTextField_08": null,
    "FreeTextField_09": null,
    "FreeTextField_10": null,
    "GLCostsCode": null,
    "GLCostsDescription": null,
    "GLCosts": null,
    "GLRevenueCode": null,
    "GLRevenueDescription": null,
    "GLRevenue": null,
    "GLStockCode": null,
    "GLStockDescription": null,
    "GLStock": null,
    "ID": "eece9df4-bf5d-4986-8429-76beb6e519cc",
    "IsBatchItem": 0,
    "IsMakeItem": 0,
    "IsNewContract": 0,
    "IsOnDemandItem": 0,
    "IsRegistrationCodeItem": 0,
    "IsWebshopItem": 0,
    "ItemGroupCode": null,
    "ItemGroupDescription": null,
    "Modified": null,
    "ModifierFullName": null,
    "Modifier": null,
    "Notes": null,
    "SalesVatCodeDescription": null,
    "SalesVatCode": null,
    "SecurityLevel": null,
    "UnitDescription": null
}
```

Comment: @PatrickHofman I'll edit my question with the json. I am using https://github.com/picqer/exact-php-client as base of operations. About the code: Yes, I double checked it  by making a product on the website. I retrieved it through the api and got the 'pc' got as Unit.

Comment: @PatrickHofman I did, or did I miss understand? I checked if the Unit with code pc exists. Made a product with it on the website. Retrieved the product with the API. Got the Unit of that and passed it on to new product. The same error occurs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get this error message because the SecurityLevel has the wrong type.
The error message should have been more clear. If you try it now, you should get an error message which gives you more detail (at least it did for me). This has been modified with an update of Exact Online.

Comment: You might want to disclose you are an employee. Often it is appreciated you are open about such things if you post here.

Comment: Agree Patrick. As Patrick stated, I'm an employee. Trying to help where we can.

Comment: Spending your late Sunday here. Sad ;)

Comment: Updated profile as well. @ Patrick : Sunday well spent, I would say :)